# How can I have my code look through a website's code and pick out a certain item?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to have a code that can search through a website's html and find a certain item, then print that item. In my code, I use a file called getPageSource.js, to get the html, and if I wanted, I could print out the whole html. Let me post that here:

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
            html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }

    return html;
}


chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

This code can allow me to open a website, and click on my extension, and my extension will open a page that will print out the HTML code. One issue solved. Now the main question is that I want my code to search through that HTML code and print out ONLY a certain item. Say I want it to print out the ID of a textbox on the page.

Let's use the Facebook login page as an example:
SO the WHOLE HTML code gets printed out, and this part is the main focus:

```
<input id= "email" class= "inputtext" type="email" tabindex="1" value= "" name="email" ></input>
```

This is one of the lines of code from the facebook.com login page. This line is specifically the code of the Email or Phone textbox. See how it says, id= "email" ? That is the part I would like my extension to print out only. SO when I click it, it just says "email" and under that the id of the one for the password box.

This is still for the same project of the extension signing in for me, and I would like to add this as a little feature, so that hopefully it can sign in to more websites for me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Simple html dom might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `DOMtoString` function when you can simply use `document.documentElement.innerHTML` and as for your question I also don't understand why you can't simply use  `document.querySelector("#email").outerHTML`.

Comment: I don't understand WHY i don't understand. Thank you, and I will try that. :)